# Require a stored procedure using for loops and temporary tables

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, for-loop

I have a requirement like need to show Target amount,collection amount,percentage of each day on that current month
Ex:This month have 30 days means 1/4/2013, I have 3  columns, 2/4/2013 have 3 more columns like that.

I have achieve this one in code behind side using for loops etc..in C# windows application but its taking too much time to load
can you please give me any stored pocedure or functions using temporary table for the above task

Comment: can you provide the table structure you are populating in memory/in your code?

Comment: I am not sure about your table structure but i think your task can be done with group by in sql as far i understand your description .

Comment: a loop is probably the worst possible design for this; sql server works very efficiently with "set" operations; aggregating data by some value (i.e. group / partition) ***is*** a "set" operation, and will typically be your best option